# discord.py v2.0 listening event logging for channel overwrite changes

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to listen for updates to a channel (logging event features for a discord bot).

The main thing I want to listen for are updates to the role permissions in the channel (overwrites). I don't know what role is going to be modified or what perms are going to be added/removed.

What I want to know/log is what role was modified the the channel and what permissions for that role was added/removed. To which I will then add the information to an embed field and send to a logging channel.

I have tried to look through the documentation, I couldn't find anything to really help me in this VERY specific case.

I have tried looking through this website for results for what I wrote as the title and found no results.

I have even tried to use AI and even that was failing to work.

This is the code I am working with:

```py
# "admin" is the same as "Client". 
channel_edit = config["channel_events"]["channel_edit"]
if channel_edit == True:
    @admin.event
    async def on_guild_channel_update(before, after):
        async for audit_log in after.guild.audit_logs(limit=5, action=discord.AuditLogAction.channel_update):
            if audit_log.target.id == after.id:
                channel_editor = audit_log.user
            break

        # overwrites being modified is different from channel_updates in the audit log..
        if before.overwrites != after.overwrites:
            async for audit_log in after.guild.audit_logs(limit=5, action=discord.AuditLogAction.overwrite_update):
                if audit_log.target.id == after.id:
                    channel_editor = audit_log.user
                break

        channel_edit_embed = discord.Embed(title=f'{emoji1} Channel updated!  |  `@{before.name}` {emoji2}\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n\nChannel Id: {before.id}\nUpdated By: @{channel_editor}\n\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\u200B\n\u200B\n', colour=hex_yellow, timestamp=datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc))
        if before.name != after.name:
            channel_edit_embed.add_field(name="Name Changed", value=f"`@{before.name}` -> `@{after.name}`\u200B\n\u200B\n", inline=False)

        if before.topic != after.topic:
            channel_edit_embed.add_field(name="Topic Changed", value=f"`{before.topic}` -> `{after.topic}`\u200B\n\u200B\n", inline=False)

        if before.category != after.category:
            channel_edit_embed.add_field(name="Category Changed", value=f"`{before.category}` -> `{after.category}`\u200B\n\u200B\n", inline=False)


        if before.overwrites != after.overwrites:
            pass
            # overwrites logging here




        channel_edit_embed.add_field(name="-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-", value="\u200B\n", inline=False)
        channel_edit_embed.set_thumbnail(url=channel_editor.avatar.url)
        channel_edit_embed.set_footer(text=__authors__, icon_url=author_logo)
        channel = admin.get_channel(mod_log_channel)
        await channel.send(embed=channel_edit_embed)
```

Everything else here works just fine and is logging without error. (could it be better, sure..idk) But what I need help with is the overwrites updates. I am not quite sure where to start or how to make it work and I am at a loss at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If anyone has any questions, I'll be more than happy to help answer them when I am available.